# Display CSV with Tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

For my assessment I am attempting to create a password manager and display a list of information into different columns and rows with tkinter. The issue is that the information doesn't stay in line and gets put lower than the pervious. This is making it so the information is not aligned correctly. I have attempted increasing per line and padding but this makes the issue worse.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import csv

global passScreen

# Create and set the GUI for the passScreen of the Password Manager.
passScreen = Tk()
passScreen.geometry("1200x800")
passScreen.resizable(width=False, height=False)
passScreen.title("Password")

Label(passScreen, text="Type").grid(row=3, column=1, padx=40)
Label(passScreen, text="Username").grid(row=3, column=2, padx=40)
Label(passScreen, text="Password").grid(row=3, column=3, padx=40)
Label(passScreen, text="Name").grid(row=3, column=4, padx=40)
Label(passScreen, text="Specific").grid(row=3, column=5, padx=40)
Label(passScreen, text="Date Created").grid(row=3, column=6, padx=40)
Label(passScreen, text="Date Updated").grid(row=3, column=7, padx=40)

passfile = open("PassManager.txt", "r")
read = csv.reader(passfile)
data = list(read)

entrieslist = []

i = 0
for entries in list(range(0, len(data))):
    entrieslist.append(data[entries][0])

    Label(passScreen, text=data[entries][1]).grid(rowspan=i + 4, column=1)
    Label(passScreen, text=data[entries][2]).grid(rowspan=i + 4, column=2)
    Label(passScreen, text=data[entries][3]).grid(rowspan=i + 4, column=3)
    Label(passScreen, text=data[entries][4]).grid(rowspan=i + 4, column=4)
    Label(passScreen, text=data[entries][5]).grid(rowspan=i + 4, column=5)
    Label(passScreen, text=data[entries][6]).grid(rowspan=i + 4, column=6)
    Label(passScreen, text=data[entries][7]).grid(rowspan=i + 4, column=7)

passScreen.mainloop()
```

PasswordManager.txt:

```
Matt,Application,111111111,1111111,11111,N/A,2022-02-07 14:21:28.481304,2022-02-07 14:21:28.481304
Matt,Application,222,1111111,111122,N/A,2022-02-07 14:24:20.892781,2022-02-07 14:24:20.892781
Matt,Application,222,1111111,111122,N/A,2022-02-07 14:24:21.596781,2022-02-07 14:24:21.596781
Matt,Website,gsdgsd,1212,1243dsg,gsdgsd,2022-02-07 14:24:26.385282,2022-02-07 14:24:26.385282
Matt,Website,gsdgsd,1212,1243dsg,gsdgsd,2022-02-07 14:24:27.053781,2022-02-07 14:24:27.053781
Matt,Application,gsdgsdg,sdgsdg,gsdgsd,N/A,2022-02-07 14:24:31.437782,2022-02-07 14:24:31.437782
Matt,Game,sdgsdgsdgsd,sgsd,sdgsd,gsdgds,2022-02-07 14:24:36.802780,2022-02-07 14:24:36.802780
Matt,Game,sdgsdgsdgsd,sgsd,sdgsd,gsdgds,2022-02-07 14:24:36.802780,2022-02-07 14:24:36.802780
```

(I am sorry if my formatting for Stack overflow is incorrect!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be accessing the data "the hard way" because it can done simply in Python. I've fixed that and also fixed your display problems (I think). Don't know why you were using `rowspan`, since I don't think it is necessary — but again, I may not have understood what you how the display to look like (could only guess from from your somewhat convoluted code).

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk  # PEP 8 recommends against `import *`.

# Create and set the GUI for the passScreen of the Password Manager.
passScreen = tk.Tk()
passScreen.geometry("1200x800")
passScreen.resizable(width=False, height=False)
passScreen.title("Password")

col_names = ("Type", "Username", "Password", "Name", "Specific", "Date Created",
             "Date Updated")
for i, col_name in enumerate(col_names, start=1):
    tk.Label(passScreen, text=col_name).grid(row=3, column=i, padx=40)

with open("PassManager.txt", "r", newline="") as passfile:
    reader = csv.reader(passfile)
    data = list(reader)

entrieslist = []
for i, row in enumerate(data, start=4):
    entrieslist.append(row[0])
    for col in range(1, 8):
        tk.Label(passScreen, text=row[col]).grid(row=i, column=col)

passScreen.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of result]

Comment: Thank you so much! This has completely fixed my issue, I have a problem with over complicating things, thank you so much! (I would give you a upvote but my reputation is not high enough ':D )

Comment: You're welcome. The over-complicating things often happens to folks who are used to using other languages — don't know if that applies to you or not — where it often *is* harder to do things because those others lack Python's abilities.

Comment: Yes! That is one thing I noticed moving from C++! Everything just sort of works with Python! haha! Thank you again!

Comment: I have a similar background. Tip: If you ever find yourself wanting to use `range(len(something))` there's usually a better way in Python. Also, regardless of what language you're using, strive to keep things [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).